# Is it ok to compare pair of Seq in Scala using ==?

Tags: scala

Consider the following code:

```
case class Foo(foo:Long, bar:Long)

type Bar = (Seq[Foo], Seq[Foo])

val a:Bar = (Seq(Foo(1, 2), Foo(2, 3)), Seq(Foo(3, 4), Foo(5, 6))) 

val b:Bar = (Seq(Foo(1, 2), Foo(3, 4)), Seq(Foo(3, 4))) 

val c:Bar = (Seq(Foo(1, 2), Foo(2, 3)), Seq(Foo(3, 4), Foo(5, 6))) 

a == b // false

a == c // true
```

How and why does this work? 
It seems to work as expected. Should I continue using it?

EDIT: I am not trying to define a new operator. My question is why the above works as expected rather than me having to define a new one. So the question is kind of "opposite" to the one linked.

Comment: Not sure if this is duplicate. I am not trying to define a new operation but want to know why the built in == works.

Comment: By convention whenever it even remotely makes sense to do so, Scala classes implement value equality - to the extent that failing to do so is essentially an implementation error. There are no operators in Scala so `a == b` is `a.==(b)`. `a.eq(b)` corresponds to `a == b` in Java.

Answer (score 6):

To quote the documentation:
http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/equality

> The collection libraries have a uniform approach to equality and hashing. The idea is, first, to divide collections into sets, maps, and sequences. Collections in different categories are always unequal. For instance, Set(1, 2, 3) is unequal to List(1, 2, 3) even though they contain the same elements. On the other hand, within the same category, collections are equal if and only if they have the same elements (for sequences: the same elements in the same order). For example, List(1, 2, 3) == Vector(1, 2, 3), and HashSet(1, 2) == TreeSet(2, 1).
>
> It does not matter for the equality check whether a collection is mutable or immutable. For a mutable collection one simply considers its current elements at the time the equality test is performed. This means that a mutable collection might be equal to different collections at different times, depending what elements are added or removed. This is a potential trap when using a mutable collection as a key in a hashmap.

Since `Foo` is a case class, an equals method (as well as others) is generated for you automatically and this is used to determine whether the elements in the sequence are equal or not.

Comment: Does the same apply to Tuples and other Scala types? This seems to talk only of collections.

Comment: The way you have written your question seems to indicate that you want to know if two collections can be compared. With regards to the other types in Scala and how equality works in their respective cases is a big topic as it depends on various factors. A good place to start reading about how Scala came about it's equality semantics is to read this: http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/object-equality.html

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it works. Probably you are asking because you are familiar with Java where `==` generally only does what you want for primitives; but Scala's `==` is really Java's `equals` (except it works for `null`) and in the rare cases when you want Java's `==` for objects, it's called `eq` in Scala.

This also means that to change behavior of `==` for your own types, you should override `equals` (and follow [the usual contract](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)), not define a `==` method.

Comment: He used a case class and so the equals method is auto-generated for it.